# Shorten an already short mathematical expression

Tags: code-golf, math, number, pi

For once, I was doing some real work, updating old code, and bumped into an expression that is equivalent to what would be written as ***πx + e<sup>x</sup>*** in good old-fashioned math. I thought it would be possible to write it shorter than it was written in the language I work with (APL), and therefore present this very simple challenge:

Write a function or program that (by any means) accepts zero or more numbers, and returns (by any means) the result of the above expression for ***x =*** *each of the given numbers* with at least 3 significant digits for each result.

If your language does not have ***π*** and/or ***e***, use the values 3.142 and 2.718.

Scoring is number of bytes, so preface your answer with `# LanguageName, 00 bytes`.

Standard loop-holes are not allowed.

---

Edit: Now the solution I came up with, `○+*`, [has been found](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67278/43319). The original code was `(○x)+*x`.

Comment: What domain are the inputs drawn from? Integers, reals, complex numbers?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Whatever you like, as long as the output isn't restricted to integer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Dyalog APL, 3 characters

As a tacit phrase.

```
○+*
```

Monadic `○` multiplies its argument with π, monadic `*` is the exponential function `exp`. `○+*` is a train such that `(○+*)ω` is equal to `(○ω)+(*ω)`. Since this is APL, the phrase works for arguments of arbitrary shape, e. g. you can pass a vector of arbitrary length.

The same solution is possible in J as `o.+^` with `o.` being `○` and `^` being `*`.

Comment: :-) See "Edit:" in OP.

Comment: So, I down voted you by mistake and only just realized. Mind making some minor edit so I can change that?

Comment: @dohaqatar7 Like this?

Answer (score 29):

## Emotinomicon, 48 bytes / 13 characters

*I do it, not because it is short, but because it is fun.* [Try it here.](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Emotinomicon/int.html) You'll have to copy+paste it into the textbox.

```
⏪✖➕⏩
```

Explanation:

```
  ⏪       ✖       ➕         ⏩   explanation
                                              take numeric input
    ⏪                                           open loop
                                              duplicate top of stack
                                              push pi
                ✖                               multiply top two elements on stack
                                              reverse stack
                                              pop N, push e^N
                            ➕                   add top two elements on stack
                                              take numeric input
                                              duplicate top of stack
                                              pop N, push N+1
                                            ⏩   close loop
```

Here is the program in its native environment, the mobile phone:
[image: the image]

Comment: Definitely the most entertaining expression.

Comment: Lol, a cat for `cat`?

Comment: I want this language.

Comment: I suppose you could say he use sub-_expressions_. (•_•) ( •_•)>⌐■-■ (⌐■_■)

Answer (score 9):

## R, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
cat(exp(x<-scan())+pi*x)
```

Is this it? It gets input from user, assign it to `x`, calculates its exponential multiply it to `pi`, and finally `cat()`prints the result.

edit: 1 bytes saved thanks to [Alex A.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20469/alex-a)

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: 24 bytes: `cat(exp(x<-scan())+pi*x)`

Comment: In this case you have to use `<-` as I did in my suggestion rather than `=` because otherwise it's setting the `x` argument for `exp` but not assigning the variable `x`. In a fresh session the current code will fail.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>39</s> 34 bytes

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to @edc65*

```
a=>a.map(x=>x*Math.PI+Math.exp(x))
```

Takes input as an array of numbers, and outputs in the same format.

Thanks to the reduction, there are now three equivalent 45-byte programs, all ES5-compliant:

```
for(;x=prompt();)alert(x*Math.PI+Math.exp(x))
for(M=Math;x=prompt();)alert(x*M.PI+M.exp(x))
with(Math)for(;x=prompt();)alert(x*PI+exp(x))
```

Inputs should be entered one at a time.  Press OK without entering anything to quit.

The third one highlights an interesting feature in JS: the `with` statement. While sometimes unsafe to use (thus disabled in strict mode), it can still be used to save typing out an object name and period every time you need to access it. For example, you can do this:

```
x=[];with(x)for(i=0;i<5;i++)push(length);
```

`push` and `length` are then used as properties of `x`, which will result with `x` being `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

This works on *any* object, even non-variables, so for example, you can do this:

```
with("0123456789ABCDEF")for(i=0;i<length;i++)alert("0x"+charAt(i)-0);
```

`charAt` and `length` are called as properties of the string. `"0x"+x-0` converts `x` from a hex value to a number, so this `alert`s the numbers 0 through 15.

Comment: `M.pow(M.E,x)` is `M.exp(x)` by definition

Comment: @edc65 I should learn my `Math` ;) Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know `with` was deprecated.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ My bad; it's not deprecated, but [avoiding it is highly suggested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with#Ambiguity_contra).

Comment: That's what I remember reading. ^_^ I use it anyways in `<canvas>` rendering and (of course) golfing.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>11</s>  13

```
VQ+*N.n0^.n1N
```

Now takes `x` as a list, e.g. `[1.25, 2.38, 25]`

Previous (11 bytes): `+*Q.n0^.n1Q`

```
VQ            +       * N .n0            ^ .n1 N
For each      Add     List Item * Pi     e ^ List Item
input item
```

Comment: When I try this with the online interpreter, it only works for a single number. Or what is the input format? The specification says that the input is "zero or more numbers", and the expression has to be evaluated for "each of the given numbers."

Comment: @RetoKoradi you can run it with multiple numbers (on separate lines) by checking the "switch to test suite" box. I'm not sure if that's allowed now that you mention it.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>11</s>  10 bytes

```
N@Pi#+E^#&
```

With 1 byte saved thanks to LegionMammal978.

Comment: This currently does not work. However, for 10 bytes: `1.Pi#+E^#&`

Comment: There was a space missing between `#` and `Pi`. This is solved by using `Pi#` in place of `#Pi`. Also, `N` only needs to be applied to `Pi#`, not the whole expression.

Answer (score 5):

### Seriously, 10 bytes

```
,`;e(╦*+`M
```

Hex Dump:

```
2c603b6528cb2a2b604d
```

[Try It Online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=2c603b6528cb2a2b604d&input=[1,2,3,4,5])

Takes inputs as a list (see link for example).

Explanation:

```
,                               Get input list
 `      `M                      Map this function over it
  ;                             Copy the input value.
   e                            exponentiate
    (                           dig up the other copy
     ╦*                         multiply by pi
       +                        add
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 38 bytes (<s>52</s> 49 bytes w. math)

```
lambda l:[3.142*x+2.718**x for x in l]
```

If I have to use the math module:

```
from math import*
lambda l:[pi*x+e**x for x in l]
```

Input should be a list of numbers

```
f([1,2,3,4,5])

> [5.8599999999999994, 13.671524, 29.505290232, 67.143510850576007, 164.04623849186558]
```

Comment: `If your language does not have π and/or e, use the values 3.142 and 2.718.` ... Python has `pi` and `e` in the `math` module.

Comment: @ZachGates Added a version with math module.

Comment: You can save 3 bytes on the `math` solution by using `from math import*`

Comment: You can also shave off another by using `for x in l:lambda l:pi*x+e**x` instead of the comprehension in both answers

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, 15 bytes

```
@(x)pi*x+exp(x)
```

Answer (score 5):

## TI-BASIC, 5 bytes

```
πAns+e^(Ans
```

TI-BASIC doesn't use ASCII bytes, so each of these is stored as one byte in the calculator: `π`, `Ans`, `+`, `e^(`, and `Ans`. It assumes the previous expression is the input (like `{1,2,3}`).

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 9 bytes

This answer uses the current version of the language ([3.1.0](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/3.1.0)), which is earlier than the challenge.

```
itYP*wZe+
```

Input is a vector containing all numbers (list enclosed by square brackets and separated by spaces, commas of semicolons), such as `[5.3 -7 3+2j]`. Complex values are allowed. Output has 15 significant digits.

#### Example

```
>> matl itYP*wZe+
> [1 2 3]
5.859874482048839 13.67224140611024 29.51031488395705
```

#### Explanation

Straightforward operations:

```
i       % input  
t       % duplicate 
YP      % pi   
*       % multiplication
w       % swap elements in stack                           
Ze      % exponential                                      
+       % addition
```

Answer (score 4):

### MATLAB: 70 bytes

```
@(x)num2str(arrayfun(@(x)(round(pi*x+exp(x),2-floor(log10(pi*x+exp(x))))),x))
```

Test:

```
ans(1:10)
5.86            13.7            29.5            67.2             164             422            1120            3010            8130           22100
```

Explanation: There were several issues with number formatting.

Firstly, the question requires 3 sig-figs. Matlab has no built-in function for rounding by sig-figs (only by decimal places), so the following workaround was required:

`floor(log10(pi*x+exp(x))))` computes the largest significant digit.

`@(x)(round(pi*x+exp(x),2-floor(log10(pi*x+exp(x))))),x))` takes input `x` and rounds to 3 significant digits.

Another requirement was to handle multiple inputs. The above code can work only with single number. To mitigate this, we use `arrayfun` to evaluate the function for each vector element.

The last problem, Matlab displays the result of arrayfun with its own rounding that leads to outputs like `1.0e+04 * 0.0006` which violates the 3 sig-fig requirement. So, `num2str` was used to turn array into `char` format.

Matlab is good for numerical analysis, but, frankly, it sucks when it comes to fine number formatting

UPD: well, that's embarrassing that I confused

> with at least 3 significant digits

with

> with 3 significant digits

Anyway, I'll leave my answer in this form because the 15 bytes Matlab solution is already given by @costrom

Comment: What?! Why do you have to do all that?

Comment: Is this code-bowling?

Comment: I'll add explanations for the answer

Comment: it only says a *minimum* of 3 sig figs, not exactly 3. if you specified that `format longg` was required before running the code, you'd drop 3/4 the length here

Comment: @costrom Yes, you're right, and I concede that you win :)

Comment: Found the numerical analyst.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 12 bytes

```julia
x->π*x+e.^x
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts an array and returns an array of floats. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=x->...`.

Julia has built-in constants `π` and `e` for—you guessed it—π and e, respectively. The `.^` operator is vectorized exponentiation.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```
map(\x->pi*x+exp x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P802N7FAI6ZC164gU6tCO7WiQKFC839uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKaQrShjpGOcex/AA)

Edit: -3 bytes thanks to @H.PWiz

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 12 bytes

```
N®*M.P+M.EpZ
```

Takes input as space-separated numbers. [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=Tq4qTS5QK00uRXBa&input=MSAyIDMgNCA1)

#### How it works

```
N®   *M.P+M.EpZ
NmZ{Z*M.P+M.EpZ

        // Implicit: N = array of inputs, M = Math object
NmZ{    // Map each item Z in N to:
Z*M.P+  //  Z times PI, plus
M.EpZ   //  E to the power of Z.
        // Implicit: output last expression
```

Comment: I hated to upvote you when you're at 5,554 rep.

Answer (score 3):

## J, 4 bytes

```
o.+^
```

Same as APL `○+*`, but J's `pi times` function is called `o.`, which is one byte longer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Par](http://ypnypn.github.io/Par/), 8 bytes

```
✶[″℗↔π*+
```

Accepts input as `(1 2 3)`

### Explanation

```
               ## [implicit: read line]
✶              ## Parse input as array of numbers
[              ## Map
 ″             ## Duplicate
 ℗             ## e to the power
 ↔             ## Swap
 π*            ## Multiply by π
 +             ## Add
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 13 bytes

```
q~{_P*\me+}%p
```

Takes input as an array separated by spaces (e.g. `[1 2 3]`). [Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%7B_P*%5Cme%2B%7D%25p&input=%5B1%202%203%5D)

#### Explanation

```
q~    e# Read the input and evaluate it as an array
{     e# Do this for each number x in the array...
  _P* e# Multiply x by pi
  \me e# Take the exponential of x (same as e^x)
  +   e# Add the two results together
}%
p     e# Pretty print the final array with spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](http://racket-lang.org), 27 bytes

```
map(λ(x)(+(* pi x)(exp x)))
```

when put in the function position of an expression:

```
(map(λ(x)(+(* pi x)(exp x))) '(1 2 3 4))

> '(5.859874482048838 13.672241406110237 29.510314883957047 67.16452064750341)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Reng v.3.3, 53 bytes

Noncompeting because it postdates the challenge, but hey, not winning any awards for brevity. :P [Try it here!](https://jsfiddle.net/Conor_OBrien/avnLdwtq/)

```
2²5³*:"G"(%3+i#II*ZA*9+(%2+#E1II0e1+ø
1-)E*(:0eø
$+n~
```

### Line 0

Here is a view of the stack in line 0:

```
Sequence read | Stack
2²            | 4
5³            | 4 125
*             | 500
:             | 500 500
"G"           | 500 500 71
(             | 500 71 500
%             | 500 0.142
3+            | 500 3.142
i             | 500 3.142 <i>
#I            | 500 3.142     ; I <- i
I             | 500 3.142 <i>
*             | 500 3.142*<i>
ZA            | 500 3.142*<i> 35 10
*             | 500 3.142*<i> 350
9+            | 500 3.142*<i> 359
(             | 3.142*<i> 359 500
%             | 3.142*<i> 0.718
2+            | 3.142*<i> 2.718
#E            | 3.142*<i>     ; E <- 2.718
1II0          | 3.142*<i> 1 <i> <i> 0
e             | 3.142*<i> 1 <i> <i>==0
1+            | 3.142*<i> 1 <i> (<i>==0)+1
```

`ø` then goes to the next Nth line. When `0` is input, this goes straight to line 2. Otherwise, we go to line 1.

### Line 1

```
1-)E*(:0eø
```

This multiples E `i` times, which is `e^i`. We decrement the counter (initially `I`), multiply the STOS (our running `e` power) by E, go back to the counter, and do this (`i'` is the current counter):

```
Sequence read | Stack (partial)
              | i'
:             | i' i'
0             | i' i' 0
e             | i' i'==0
```

`ø` then does one of two things. If the counter is not 0, then we go to the "next" 0th line, i.e., the beginning of the current line. If it is zero, then `0e` yields 1, and goes to the next line.

### Line 2

```
$+n~
```

`$` drops the counter (ON THE FLOOR!). `+` adds the top two results, `n` outputs that number, and `~` quits the program.

Case 1: input is 0. The TOS is 1 ("e^0") and the STOS is 0 (pi*0). Adding them yields the correct result.

Case 2: input is not 0. The result is as you might expect.